# Does one say "Where?" or "Where at?"

Tags: grammar

Like when someone says, "Hey, look at that girl!"... are you supposed to say "Where?" or "Where at?" What's the difference?

Comment: _Where_ means 'where at'. _Where to_ and _where from_ require the directional words.

Answer (score 1):

You  just need "where"; no need to dangle the preposition "at." But "which girl" would be a more definitive way of specifying the girl (the actual information you may be trying to determine) rather than her location.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *"Where at?"* is used when the location is not hinted at by the prompting statement. Ex:

"There's going to be a big party tonight."  "Where at?"

"I saw your crazy ex-wife yesterday."  "Where at?"

Note that a simple *"Where?"* would work in these instances.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I completely disagree.  There's no grammatical reason to add "at" to either of those examples.

Comment: I didn't say it was grammatical. It's an expression.

Comment: It's **bad English** and it's not used regularly... if you look at the question "Does one say "Where?" or "Where at?" your answer makes it look like "where at" is the correct option, when it is not and you don't even mention that it is idiomatic and non-grammatical.

Comment: @Catija While 'Where at?' is unacceptable in response to the example OP gives, Oldbag is at least partly correct in what she says. And the title question licenses her answer. I'd not label 'Where at?' uncommon or 'bad English' in an example with an unspecified venue (her first example), though I'd not think it appropriate for the second example. I can see no fundamental rule allowing sentence-fragment questions of the form 'Where?' but disallowing those of the form 'Where at?' And I'd choose 'Where to?' in response to 'I'm going abroad next week'.